# A comedian's lies

Tags: rhyme, cryptic-clues

> *Comedian's hollow lies
>
>   'bout the bottom of the lake:
>
>   "The head of the snake
>
>   with a ring in day's break".*  (3 6)

Who are we describing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The person is

> Les Dawson

Comedian's hollow lies

> L(ie)S

'bout the bottom of the lake:

> lakE

"The head of the snake

> Snake

with a ring in day's break".

> ring=O, day's break=DAWN

Put together

> LES DAWSON who is a comedian