# Is there a limerick-style cryptic clue?

Tags: cryptic-clues, poetry, limerick

Is there a cryptic clue that happens to be a limerick?
Please also include the answer in spoilers.

Comment: $$\frac{(12+144+20)+\left(3 \cdot \sqrt{4}\right)}{7}+(5 \cdot 11)=9^2+0\quad(6\text-3)$$ if you want to stretch both the definitions of "limerick" and "cryptic clue".

Comment: @boboquack What's the answer? I'm not good at **solving** cryptic clues.

Comment: I found [this](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/84446/a-comedians-lies) poem, but it's not a limerick. Also, The poem that you should give must have rhyme.

Comment: [Here's the limerick](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/879179/376258), and the answer is literally ([rot13](https://rot13.com/)) rvtugl-bar (qbhoyr qrsvavgvba).

Comment: Please post the poem in your answer.

Comment: I suddenly earned "one thousand reputation"

Comment: ^ That's your Stack Exchange [association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus) - when you reach 200 rep on one site in the Stack Exchange network you automatically earn an extra 100 rep on every site in the network you are a member of, since you've now demonstrated you know how the system works. It's a good (and deliberate) thing!

Comment: The association bonus is one *hundred*, not one *thousand* - is that what you meant?

Comment: I found some [limericks *about* cryptic clues](https://www.crosswordunclued.com/2010/04/limericks-for-nj.html), but that doesn't count :-)

Answer (score 6):

My try:

> A visitor of cleaning station
>   (a person of male persuasion)
>   does darken his skin
>   (there is no point therein)
>   by a beam of the Sun's radiation
>   (5 3)

Answer:

> Definition
>  `A visitor of cleaning station     = MANTA RAY`<sup>[[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleaning_station)</sup>
>
>  Wordplay
>  `(a person of male persuasion)     = MAN`
>  `does darken his skin              = TANS`
>  `(there is no point therein)       = remove N,S (compass points) -> TA`
>  `by a beam of the Sun's radiation  = RAY`

Comment: is it ... ray? +1

Comment: Nice effort :) Alternative first line: "A sea dweller (fish, not crustacean)"... +1

Comment: @Stiv That would certainly fit the metre better. Not sure about the surface reading, though. (Although it has to be said that [some fish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ocean_sunfish) do in fact sunbathe.)

Answer (score 5):

Though I'm not sure whether it's worthy of an answer, since the OP encouraged me to post it, there is the well-known mathematical limerick

$$\frac{(12+144+20)+\left(3 \cdot \sqrt{4}\right)}{7}+(5 \cdot 11)=9^2+0$$

or

```
A dozen, a gross, and a score
Plus three times the square root of four
Divided by seven
Plus five times eleven
Is nine squared and not a bit more.
```

which can be repurposed to make a cryptic clue by adding (6-3) on the end, with answer

> EIGHTY-ONE (double definition)

though it's incredibly debatable whether this is really a cryptic clue (and, in the non-textual version, whether it is really a limerick).

Comment: Nah, that's not a *cryptic* clue. It's a crossword clue, but not a cryptic one. Cryptic clues, at least for [pedants like this community](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/14524?m=51369120#51369120), have a stricter definition.

Comment: @Randal'Thor exactly why I claim it's incredibly debatable (for example, even if there are two parts which resolve to the answer, they're not substantially different, nor are they definitions), and why I posted as a comment. But the OP asked me to post an answer, so...

Answer (score 5):

I've never seen them before in the wild, but that doesn't mean you can't just make them up... For example here's a pair of cryptic limericks I just wrote:

> A challenging type of cross word,
>   Whose clues border on the absurd.
>   Initia'ly perplex
>   Thoughtful intellects...
>   Called after, perhaps: "Oh, my word!"

(7)

> Rhymed words with particular rhythm
>   (Often times nonsense within 'em):
>   A "green citrus fruit";
>   One "odd cakes" to boot;
>   Between: "centre for algorithm".

(9)

---

**Answers** (which I forgot to add initially):

> **CRYPTIC**
>  Def: "A challenging type of cross word, / Whose clues border on the absurd."
>  Initially **P**(erplex) **T**(houghtful) **I**(ntellects) **C**(alled) (placed *after*)
>  [Placed] after **CRY** (of which "Oh, my word" is an example of)

and:

> **LIMERICKS**
>  Def: "Rhymed words with particular rhythm / (Often times nonsense within 'em)"
>  **LIME** (A green citrus fruit)
>  **I** (one) + odd **C**(a)**K**(e)**S**
>  With (algo)**R**(ithm) between

---

<sub><sup>This is almost certainly too broad but I can't resist [this sort](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5306/various-virtuosic-variety) of [challenge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/30553/riddles-whose-answer-is-the-moon) and wish it could [find a home here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5658/would-puzzle-construction-challenge-questions-be-off-topic-for-this-site) in some form, so am going to turn a blind eye...</sup></sub>

Comment: It's not a challenge.

Comment: @Scratch---Cat - I realise you're not posing a challenge directly, but when the answer to your question is certain to take the form "yes, and here's an example", how are you going to choose the "correct" answer? Given that you can't, you'll have to just choose the "best", which means it effectively becomes a challenge without you intending.

Comment: I figured when you italicized cryptic limerick before that I could guess what they were, but man the parsing on this one is brilliant — well done!

Comment: I am not going to choose the best.

Comment: I'm asking them to find an existing one (such as in the Guardians).